# Camera freezes in some devices

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using custom camera in my app. It works fine in most of the devices but the camera freezes in some of the newer devices (Note 8, OnePlus 5). Works fine in S7 and OnePlus3(with Android O). Camera freezes but the app does not crash until the capture button is pressed.

It is not the issue of wrong preview size/picture size,I think, because I have generated the optimal preview size using one of the size from getSupportedPreviewSizes. Here is the log :

```
03-06 08:16:52.744 15930-15930/my.example.app D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
03-06 08:16:52.748 15930-15930/my.example.app D/UI: Activity paused: 
MainActivity
03-06 08:16:52.761 15930-15930/my.example.app D/UI: Activity created: CustomCameraActivity
03-06 08:16:52.813 15930-15930/my.example.app D/CustomCameraActivity: viewCardPhoto height :530 width :-2
03-06 08:16:52.814 15930-15930/my.example.app D/UI: Activity started: CustomCameraActivity
03-06 08:16:52.817 15930-15930/my.example.app D/UI: Activity resumed: CustomCameraActivity
03-06 08:16:52.817 15930-15930/my.example.app D/AppTracker: App Event: start
03-06 08:16:52.870 15930-15930/my.example.app **E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.hal1.packagelist"**
03-06 08:16:52.861 15930-15930/my.example.app W/example.app: type=1400 audit(0.0:39722): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17899 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
03-06 08:16:53.060 15930-15930/my.example.app I/CustomCameraActivity: setting camera preview size
03-06 08:16:53.065 15930-15930/my.example.app D/CustomCameraActivity: width: 1080 hieght: 2034
03-06 08:16:53.065 15930-15930/my.example.app D/CustomCameraActivity: sc W: 1080 sc H: 2034
03-06 08:16:53.069 15930-15930/my.example.app **E/CustomCameraActivity: Error starting camera preview: setParameters failed**
03-06 08:16:53.478 15930-15930/my.example.app D/UI: Activity save instance state: CardHolderActivity
03-06 08:16:53.485 15930-15930/my.example.app D/UI: Activity stopped: MainActivity
```

Has anyone else faced this issue? Or knows what's the reason behind this?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_camera_activity);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // camera surface view created
    cameraId = CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    buttonRotateCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonCaptureImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFlash.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageCloseCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    setFrameMeasurement();
    viewFinderView.setFrame(viewCardPhoto);
    viewFinderView3.setFrame(viewCardPhoto3);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    context = this;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(getTargetSdkVersion() >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                askForPermission();
            else
                isPermissionGranted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Permission for Camera is required for using this. Please turn on the Camera permission.");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                alertBuilder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                alertBuilder.show();
            }
            else
                isPermissionGranted = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (isPermissionGranted && !openCamera(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)) {
        alertCameraDialog();
        setUpCamera();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
    if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        Log.i(TAG, "setting camera preview size");
        Camera.Parameters cameraSettings = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size previewSize = optimimalPreviewSize(width, height);
        Log.d(TAG, "width: " + width +" hieght: " + height);
        Log.d(TAG, "sc W: " + displayMetrics.widthPixels + " sc H: " + displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        //flipped
        cameraSettings.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        cameraSettings.setPictureSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(cameraSettings);
        //camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        //camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        //setFocus(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        camera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

/**
 * opens camera if available
 *
 * @param id camera id
 */
private boolean openCamera(int id) {
    boolean result = false;
    cameraId = id;
    releaseCamera();
    try {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //unable to open camera
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error opening camera");
    }
    if (camera != null) {
        try {
            setUpCamera();
            camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {

                }
            });
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            result = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
            releaseCamera();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * gets the rotation of camera of the device
 *
 */
private void setUpCamera() {
    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degree = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degree = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degree = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degree = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degree = 270;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        // frontFacing  
        rotation = (info.orientation + degree) % 330;
        rotation = (360 - rotation) % 360;
    } else {
        // Back-facing  
        rotation = (info.orientation - degree + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);
    Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

    showFlashButton(params);
    params.setRotation(rotation);
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding the part from your code where you're using the camera.

Comment: sure. I'll add my code